# cv2 face detection problem when no face was detected

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I have an application where I try to detect faces and print Hi! when face is detected. My problem is that even if the face (human) moves away from visible area, the message doesn't change. I want to print "no faces found" in that case.

How can I make an action when no face is detected, whether print something or other kind of notification as sound.

The code I have made so far:

```
import cv2
cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while 1:

    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    if len(faces) == 0:
        print
        "No faces found"
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        re = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(200,200,0),2)
        if 're' in locals():
            print('Hi')
        else:
            print('No faces found')
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imshow('Hi',img)

    # Wait for Esc key to stop
    k = cv2.waitKey(30)
    if k == 13:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking [this example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html#gsc.tab=0) for understanding how face should be detected, your condition `if 're' in locals():` checks if the variable exists in `locals()` but you create it there, you want to check faces instead and probably put them in squares and say Hi to them, once you enter the `for` loop you have face detections there.

Minimalistic code that does what you need:

```
import cv2
cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    title = "Hi!"
    if len(faces) == 0:
        title = "No faces found!" 
        #or do something else here if no faces were found...
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(200,200,0),2)
        cv2.putText(frame,'Hi!',(x + sx,y + sy), 1, 1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imshow(title,img)

    # Wait for Esc key to stop
    k = cv2.waitKey(30)
    if k == 13:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: it actually freezings on the last capture when the face moved away the camera & it prints nothing no Hi no No faces found

Comment: I believe the problem is `if 're' in locals():`, re is actually always in locals as you assign it right before the check, you probably want to check variable re if is not empty, not if it is defined because it surely is no matter what at this point

Comment: I did if 're' not in locals():
            print('Hi')
        else:
            print('No faces found') and it prints No face found. I am nit sure how to check if re empty. can you please explain more?

Comment: I have changed the code so it should ork now, not entirely sure, cant test, check out this as well:
https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-face-detection-in-python-3eab0f6b9fc1

Answer (score 1):

it's a very simple mistake

```
print
"No faces found"
```

is what is causing the error, try changing it to

```
print("No faces found")
```

What you are doing is that you are calling a print function and just defining a string and not using it

and to play sound , you can [playsound](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/).

Comment: it does nothing with or without ()

Comment: I tested the code myself before posting it, if you care to explain. i can help

Comment: i did  `while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        re = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,0),2)
        if 're':
            print("Detected")
        elif not 're':
            print("no face")
        else:
            print("whatever")
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imshow('Hi',img) ` it worked but prints only detected.

Comment: i was thinking to print detected on another window `cv2.imshow('window2', 'whatever')` to print face update